# IE grid-template-columns Workaround

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I just noticed my website is not doing a good job rendering in IE and after digging into it... grid-template-columns support appear to be the root cause.   I followed the advice of previous questions and added  the ms related tags but for some reason i am still not getting it to render nicely.

I would hate to go back to putting everything in  for spacing and was hoping to get some advice....

```
.grid-container {
     display: -ms-grid; -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
     display: grid;  grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%; }

.grid-item {text-align: center;}
```

html

```
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-item">
        First Name: <input type="text" id="inputIdentifyFirstName">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
        Last Name: <input type="text" id="inputIdentifyLastName">
    </div>
</div>
```

There is obviously more grid items i can provide if needed (the container expects 4 across) but i felt like 2 should be enough to get the picture.

Answer (score 0):

If possible for you then you can try to refer to the example below may help you to display textboxes properly in the IE browser.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
  margin: 40px;

}

/*autoprefixer will add the prefixed properties for grid and columns/rows*/
.wrapper {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid; 
  -ms-grid-columns: 300px 300px 300px;
  grid-template-columns: 300px 300px 300px;
 
}

.box {
 
 
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 100%;
}


/* in the current spec these would be postioned using auto-placement. For IE we need to set the position of the items. */
.a {
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
}

.b {
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  -ms-grid-column: 2;
}

.c {
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  -ms-grid-column: 3;
}

.d {
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  -ms-grid-column: 4;
}


}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box a"> First Name: <input type="text" id="inputIdentifyFirstName"></div>
  <div class="box b">Last Name: <input type="text" id="inputIdentifyLastName"></div>
  <div class="box c">Address: <input type="text" id="inputAddress"></div>
  <div class="box d">DOB: <input type="text" id="inputDob"></div>
 
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Output in IE 11 browser:

[image]

It may give the unexpected results in other browsers. You can apply this styles only for IE browser or you can further try to modify it according to your requirements.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me.  Sorry for the late reply!

Comment: I suggest you mark the helpful suggestion as an answer to this question. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.